# ignore return values

Tags: solidity

I have a function which returns two `uint` values:

```
function unclaimedCollateralRewardAndDebt() public view returns(uint, uint)
```

in most cases I use both returned values but sometime I need only one. Is there a way to ignore one of the returned values like in GoLang?

```
// getting both values
(uint unclaimedCollateral, uint unclaimedDebt) = unclaimedCollateralRewardAndDebt();
// get only first value
(_, uint unclaimedDebt) = unclaimedCollateralRewardAndDebt();
// get only second value
(uint unclaimedCollateral, _) = unclaimedCollateralRewardAndDebt();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// get only first value
(, uint unclaimedDebt) = unclaimedCollateralRewardAndDebt();
// get only second value
(uint unclaimedCollateral,) = unclaimedCollateralRewardAndDebt();
```

should work

Comment: what if there's more than 2 return values? can we ignore the middle one like (uint a,,uint b) ?